# Is there a way to increase the number of potions I can carry?

Tags: final-fantasy-16

I'm still in the early parts of Final Fantasy 16, and Clive can only carry 4 potions and 3 high potions. During certain boss fights, I found myself using them all early on in the fights and not having any for the later parts of the fight.

Is there a way to increase the number of potions I can carry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I put a bounty on this, I figured out there *is* a way to increase the number of potions you can carry after seeing the trophy [With Two Ds](https://psnprofiles.com/trophy/22648-final-fantasy-xvi/34-with-two-ds)

> Upgrade consumable potency and inventory slots to their maximum.

While this is possible, it cannot be done until *much* later in the game,

> after the second time skip.

The first time you obtain this upgrade is after the side quest [Weird Science](https://www.ign.com/wikis/final-fantasy-xvi/Weird_Science), and then again during [Even Weirder Science](https://www.ign.com/wikis/final-fantasy-xvi/Even_Weirder_Science) following the main quests "After the Storm" and "Across the Narrow" respectively.